# How to use the glTF loader fuction?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hello how can I do to use my gltf for example I would like to do :

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    composer.render();

    const rx = window.pageYOffset * 2;

    gltf.scene.rotation.set( rx, 0, 0);
}
animate();
```

but it doesn't work because I can't get the function's gltf object. I made the gtlf loader with the three js doc: https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader

and here is my code:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    composer.render();
}
animate();

const loader = new GLTFLoader();
// Load a glTF resource
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    'gltf/cyberpunk_laptop.glb',
    // called when the resource is loaded
    function ( gltf ) {

        scene.add( gltf.scene );
        
        gltf.scene.scale.set(1,1,1);
        gltf.scene.position.set(-1.8, -0.9, 1.2);
        gltf.scene.rotation.set(Math.PI * 1.1, Math.PI * 0.6, Math.PI * 1);
        gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
        gltf.scene; // THREE.Group
        gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Group>
        gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
        gltf.asset; // Object

    },
    // called while loading is progressing
    function ( xhr ) {

        console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

    },
    // called when loading has errors
    function ( error ) {

        console.log( 'An error happened' );

    }
```

Comment: Maybe try to add light to the scene? The object might be there but not visible. Also try to see if the scale is ok

Comment: this is not my problem everything works but i just want to set the potion of my object outside the gtlf function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const placeholder = new THREE.Group();

new GLTFLoader().load('gltf/cyberpunk_laptop.glb', gltf => {
  placeholder.add(gltf.scene);
});

// NOTE GLTF won't be available here right away, but the Group will - and since it has the same API, you can already do most of the work while GLTF is still pending
scene.add(placeholder);
placeholder.position.set(-1.8, -0.9, 1.2);
placeholder.rotation.set(Math.PI * 1.1, Math.PI * 0.6, Math.PI * 1);
```